# Attempting to display total amount_won for each user in database via For loop

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to display the Sum of amount_won for each user_name in the database. My database is:

Stakes table

```
id
player_id
stakes
amount_won
last_play_date
```

Player table

```
id
user_name
real_name
site_played
```

models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    SITE_CHOICES = (
        ('FTP', 'Full Tilt Poker'),
        ('Stars', 'Pokerstars'),
        ('UB', 'Ultimate Bet'),
    )
    site_played = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SITE_CHOICES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name
    def was_created_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()

class Stakes(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    stakes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount_won = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    last_play_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Last Updated')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stakes

class PlayerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player

class StakesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stakes
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    latest_player_list = Player.objects.all().order_by('id')[:20]
    total_amount_won = Stakes.objects.filter(player__user_name='test_username').aggregate(Sum('amount_won'))
    return render_to_response('stakeme/index.html', {
        'latest_player_list':     latest_player_list, 
        'total_amount_won': total_amount_won
     })
```

and index.html

```
<h1> Players </h1>

{% if latest_player_list %}
<ul>
{% for player in latest_player_list %}
    <li><a href="/stakeme/{{ player.id }}/">{{ player.user_name }} </a><br>Total Won: {{ total_amount_won }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<br>
{% else %}
<p>No players are available.</p>
{% endif %}

<h3><a href="/stakeme/new/">New Player</a></h3>
```

If I leave the views.py section as `(player__user_name='test_username')` it will display Amount Won: as follows `Total Won: {'amount_won__sum': Decimal('4225.00')}` using the test_username's amount_won (4225.00) for EVERY user name. Ideally, I'd like it to display Amount Won: for each user name in the for loop and display it as "Amount Won: 4225.00" only.

I'm starting to understand this is way over my head, but I've read the docs regarding the differences between aggregate and annotate and I can't wrap my head around it. I'm thinking my DB is not setup correctly to use annotate for this, but I obviously could be wrong.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed your models and not just the field names.

Comment: "total_amount_won = Stakes.objects.filter(player__user_name='test_username').aggregate(Sum('amount_won'))
" Guarantees that the `total_amount_won` is only for a specific user.  Have you done the Django tutorial yet?  Do you know how ForeignKey fields work?

Comment: Yes. I understand that it guarantees that it is for a specific user. I do NOT understand how to change that so that it is for every user in the For loop instead.

models.py added as per your request, sgallen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

```
players = Player.objects.annotate(total_amount_won=Sum('stakes__amount_won'))

players[0].total_amount_won # This will return the 'total amount won' for the 0th player
```

So you could pass `players` to your template and loop over it.

**EDIT**

Your views.py would look like:

```
def index(request):
    players = Player.objects.annotate(total_amount_won=Sum('stakes__amount_won'))
    return render_to_response('stakeme/index.html', {'players': players,})
```

The template would look like:

```
<h1> Players </h1>
{% if players %}
<ul>
{% for player in players %}
<li>
    <a href="/stakeme/{{ player.id }}/">{{ player.user_name }} </a><br>Total Won: {{ player.total_amount_won }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>    
<br />
{% else %}
<p>No players are available.</p>
{% endif %}
<h3><a href="/stakeme/new/">New Player</a></h3>
```

Comment: adding the above two lines to the end of my index definition in views.py, and then passing players like so `{% for player in latest_player_list %}
        <li><a href="/stakeme/{{ player.id }}/">{{ player.user_name }} </a><br>Total Won: {{ players }}
</li>
    {% endfor %}` results in Amount Won: with blank data for every user. Did I add it correctly? I will definitely read over the docs again as I do want the answer, but I want to learn how this works even more. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I receive `Cannot resolve keyword 'amount_won' into field. Choices are: id, real_name, site_played, stakes, user_name` in the `players =` line. I appreciate your help with this. I'm beginning to grasp what is going on. It seems that 'amount_won' is not available because it is part of the Stakes table and not the Players table, correct?

Comment: So thanks to the docs and your answer, I got it. It needs a join. It needs to be 'stakes__amount_won' rather than 'amount_won'. Again, I really appreciate your help! Thanks a ton!